# Is destroy method always called for session-scoped DisposableBean?

Tags: java, spring, websphere, session-scope

In a Spring-based application, I have a session-scoped bean that implements DisposableBean interface. Are there any circumstances when its *destroy* method will not be called on the session expiration?

The application uses Spring version: 2.0.8 and runs on WebSphere 6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, in WebSphere Network Deployment a DisposableBean may not be correctly destroyed. In a clustered environment the application server creates a copy of a session bean (with serialization/deserialization). Then, when session invalidates, it calls the `destroy` not on the original bean but on its copy. As a result, the `destroy` method on the original bean is never called in this case.